# How to create a table using the data.sql file using spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My goal is to create a database using a file, but the application does not respond to it, and if I try to add something to the database, I get an error:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BILLIONAIRE" don't found
And of course the table was not created

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

data.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS billionaires;

CREATE TABLE billionaires (
                              id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
                              first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
                              last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
                              career VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO billionaires (first_name, last_name, career) VALUES
('Aliko', 'Dangote', 'Billionaire Industrialist'),
('Bill', 'Gates', 'Billionaire Tech Entrepreneur'),
('Folrunsho', 'Alakija', 'Billionaire Oil Magnate');
```

model

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Billionaire {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String career;

}
```

Working version

```
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Comment: Did you put your .sql to src/main/resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hibernate

> In addition, a file named import.sql in the root of the classpath is
> executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that
> is, if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop). This
> can be useful for demos and for testing if you are careful but is
> probably not something you want to be on the classpath in production.
> It is a Hibernate feature (and has nothing to do with Spring).

Here you need to change ddl-auto property to create or create-drop (then you can delete CREATE TABLE command from .sql file

2. Basic SQL script

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your
> JDBC DataSource or R2DBC ConnectionFactory and initialize it (DML
> scripts). It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations:
> schema.sql and data.sql, respectively. In addition, Spring Boot
> processes the schema-${platform}.sql and data-${platform}.sql files
> (if present), where platform is the value of spring.sql.init.platform.
> This allows you to switch to database-specific scripts if necessary.
> For example, you might choose to set it to the vendor name of the
> database (hsqldb, h2, oracle, mysql, postgresql, and so on). By
> default, SQL database initialization is only performed when using an
> embedded in-memory database. To always initialize an SQL database,
> irrespective of its type, set spring.sql.init.mode to always.
> Similarly, to disable initialization, set spring.sql.init.mode to
> never. By default, Spring Boot enables the fail-fast feature of its
> script-based database initializer. This means that, if the scripts
> cause exceptions, the application fails to start. You can tune that
> behavior by setting spring.sql.init.continue-on-error

Here basically you need to add spring.sql.init.platform=h2 to your properties

Many different approaches are listed here:
[Data initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

Place your data.sql under src/main/resource of your project workspace

[image: Refer here]

And Restart your spring application.